# How to get A+ Ball Handling Grade in NBA2K14 My Career PS4?

Tags: nba2k14

I'm 94 overall rated starter on the bulls, season 2. My ball handling attribute is 92, and my ball handling grade is A, but I want it to be A+. And I can't upgrade the ball handling attribute anymore because it's maxed out at 92. Any ideas? Do I need to upgrade some thing else more?

Comment: I think that if the max is 92 you wont be able to reach a higher value. Its a way to make the game more real you cant be A+ in all stats so depending on your position you cant reach a 99 attribute

Comment: In 2k13, you could spend skill points to increase the maximum stat cap of your skills, I wonder if that's been removed in 2k14?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the other dribbling stats, such as off-hand dribbling & ball control. Most of the letter-grade attributes (Ball Handling, Perimeter Defense, Athleticism) are a combination of some numerical attributes. For example, "Rebounding" is a combination or Offensive and Defensive Rebounding.